# VirtualBox Proxy Settings with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, proxy

I have tried many many things to use Firefox to connect to the Internet.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on Oracle VirtualBox at my work.  We are behind a proxy, but I cannot get Ubuntu to allow it to go through.  The screen on the VirtualBox is very small like 640x480, and while trying to troubleshoot that issue, many tutorials said to download plugins.  I could not do that due to not having access to the Internet.  How I can I get the Internet proxy solution corrected?

Answer (score 4):

Test this:

Open a terminal.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Put the following lines in the file:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/environment
```

Put the following lines in the file

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Put the following lines in the file:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.